# Android listview get most center view position while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to get most center element view position of the listview.

[listview center view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXKxZ.png)

```
 public void getPos(final ListView listView) {
        int firstPos = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int lastPos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        int count = lastPos - firstPos;
        int viewPosition = (count - ((int) count / 2));
        //int viewPosition = (count - ((int) count / 2)+1);
}
```

and also tried with screen x,y

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        float height = size.y;
        float centerY=height/2;

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //                Log.i("Yes1", "Here");
            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    final ListView listView = (ListView) view;
                    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {
                        final View firstView = listView.getChildAt(i);
                        if (firstView != null) {
                            Log.i("Height", centerY + " | " +   firstView.getY());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried above methods but not getting accurate result while scrolling up and down. any one have solution how to get most center view position in listview?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
             String[] values = new String[]{"Android List View",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Adapter implementation",
                        "Simple List View In Android",
                        "Create List View Android",
                        "Android Example",
                        "List View Source Code",
                        "List View Array Adapter",
                        "Android Example List View"
                };



                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.row_temp, R.id.label_tv, values);
                final ListView listView = new ListView(this);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                setContentView(listView);

                listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                        if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                                if(listView.getChildAt(i)  != null) {
                                    TextView childView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.label_tv);
                                    if (childView != null) {
                                        childView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            int centerItemPosition = ((listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()) / 2);
                            TextView centerView =(TextView)listView.getChildAt(centerItemPosition).findViewById(R.id.label_tv);
                            centerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

row_temp Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/label_tv"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="skdjfksdf"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dk46.png)

Comment: I have written same code in 1st part in my question its not working while scroll up, its working fine while scroll down.

Comment: I have attach image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXKxZ.png) with your code not working